# Integration of volume using double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^3\ \int_0^x\ 3 x y\ \text{d}y\ \text{d} x = \frac{243}{8}$$

Could anyone describe how the geometric area of this integral area would be?

Answer (score 2):

It is the volume between $y=0$ and $y=x$ with $0\leq x \leq 3$ weighted by $3xy$ or under the manifold $z=3xy$ if you wish.

You can rewrite the integral as purely a volume integral as 
$$\int_0^3\ \int_0^x\ \int_0^{3 x y}\ \text{d}z\ \text{d}y\ \text{d} x $$

Comment: Looks perfect to me now!

Comment: Ok. so is this a cylinder/cuboid with height, z = 3xy?

Comment: @Victor428 No, it is a "hyperbolic paraboloid" apparently. But what about the equation suggests either of those two solids to you?

Comment: well i figured it out that it is the surface volume of a figure...

Comment: @Victor428 It is the volume beneath a surface yes, but why should it be beneath those particular surfaces?

Comment: ok so the two integrals integral (0 to 3) integral(0 to x) 3xy dydx & integral (0 to 3) integral (y to 3) 3xy dydx represent the base area of the hyperbolic paraboloid?

Comment: no they represent the volume from the xy plane up to the surface.

Comment: It is a volume, not a surface area

Answer (score 0):

Here is a graph of the region in question:

[image]